# Definition of "linear arrangement of hyperplanes"

Tags: linear-algebra

I want to understand what a **linear** arrangement of hyperplanes is. Some definitions I found say that it is an arrangement containing only *affine* hyperplanes, but what does that mean? Can you please give me a (counter-)example?

Comment: An affine hyperplane is a hyperplane that need not go through the origin. $y=17$ is an affine hyperplane in the plane.

Comment: I'd take "linear" in this context to mean that the hyperplanes are supposed to pass through the origin, as opposed to affine hyperplanes.  (One could, however, argue that the terminology is inappropriate because it is not the arrangement but the individual hyperplanes in it that are linear.)

Comment: @AndreasBlass thank you!